# Перезапускается nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, pdf

Формирую PDF файл через запрос:

```
app.get('/report/:listId', function(req, res) {
    const path = require("path");
    const ejs = require("ejs");
    const pdf3 = require('html-pdf');
    var dayTitle=dateFormat(new Date(), "dd.mm.yyyy");

    pdf.getData(req.params.listId)
    .then(r => {
      ejs.renderFile(path.join(__dirname, "/fn/report-template.ejs"), {
        list: r.list,
      }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            let options = {
                "height": "11.25in",
                "width": "8.5in",
                "header": {
                    "height": "20mm"
                },
                "footer": {
                    "height": "20mm",
                },
            };

            pdf3.create(data, options).toFile(`${dayTitle}.pdf`, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                } else {
                    res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/${dayTitle}.pdf`);
                }
            });
        }
        });
    });
});
```

Работает через раз. Но чаще всего нода просто перезапускается (PM2 --watch), при этом нет никаких ошибок. Файл 0 байт.
При этом, если этот же код запускать просто через консоль (node pdf.js), файл формируется всегда без ошибок. Как будто веб сервер обрывает запрос, не пойму...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, Ваш pdf сохраняется на диске, а pm2 с параметром --watch следит за изменениями файлов и видит, что добавился/поменялся файл и перезапускает скрипт.
Попробуйте, использовать параметр `ignore_watch` [pm2 watch and restart](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/watch-and-restart/)